# Chat on Stack Exchange app

Tags: discussion, chat, stackexchange

I've been looking all over for it but failed miserably. 
How do you get in the chat room from the Stack Exchange app for Android?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no actual chat integration with the mobile apps. There is a link that opens it in a browser on the iOS app, no idea about the Android app though.

Comment: The mobile web chat did just got a makeover recently so it's a bit easier to use now.

Comment: @CAI :( Too bad, it would've been great to actually have it integrated in the app. I simply though I couldn't find it since I actually couldn't believe it doesn't exist.

Comment: This is probably a question that you should ask on meta.stackexchange. I think it has been asked

Comment: @ZachSaucier Will do in a couple of hours. I'm all over a wood design for a sculptor's website and it's driving me crazy :))